# Create new dictionary into list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I create a new dictionary from `my_list`. Check every item and add to dictionary as a new
key and any item is same for the key then add into same as key in its value

The problem is while a new key is created its item is not append to the value to for that key.

My code:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
my_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    if item in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] = [item]
    my_dict[item] = []
print my_dict
```

output looks like this:

```
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
```

but I want it look like that:

```
{'a': ['a', 'a'], 'c': [], 'b': ['b']}
```

Comment: In the `for` loop, you **always** replace `my_dict[item] = []` at the end - why?! And you *never* `append`. Think more carefully about what the function should be doing at each step. You could make this much simpler with `my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're resetting the `list` for each `item` at the end of your for loop. Instead, try this:

```
for item in my_list:
    # First time you see an item create an empty list
    if item not in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] = []
    # Otherwise, add the item to the list
    else:
        my_dict[item].append( item )
```

Comment: Also, `my_dict.setdefault(item, []).append(item)` may replace the `if-else` clause.

Comment: @bereal almost, but then the output would be `{'a': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'b': ['b', 'b'], 'c': ['c']}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` also

```
from collections import Counter
>>>{i:[i]*(j-1) for i,j in Counter(my_list).items()}
{'a': ['a', 'a'], 'c': [], 'b': ['b']}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the desired output:

```
my_dict = dict(map(lambda x: (x, list((my_list.count(x)-1)*x)), my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in my_list:
    if item in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[item].append(item)
    else:
        my_dict[item]=[]
```

or more simple:

```
for item in set(my_list):
    my_dict[item]=[x]*(my_list.count(item)-1)
```

Comment: This won't do what is wanted, you'll have too many stuff in the lists

Comment: yes youre right, I've repaired an answer. else: my_dict[item] = []

Answer (score 0):

You're always replacing the value in the dictionary by an empty list.
You should  : add an item if the key is already present or create a new list for a new item

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
my_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    if item in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] += [item]
    else:
        my_dict[item] = [item]
print my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
You can add a list to the dict first by writing `my_dict[item] = []` and then you can append to it

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
my_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    if item not in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] = []
    else:
        my_dict[item].append(item)
print my_dict
```

Comment: `.keys()` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
my_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    if item in my_dict:
        my_dict[item] += [item]
    else:
        my_dict[item] = []
print my_dict
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['a', 'a'], 'c': [], 'b': ['b']}
```